# Installing Linux on my NXT

Tags: mindstorms, nxt

I have an old NXT laying around and I want to set it up with my printer so I can connect it to the cloud. In order to do this I need to install Linux on the NXT and connect the NXT's USB port to the OS. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Linux firmware for the NXT. The NXT has very limited resources, so running Linux is probably not a possibility.

Comment: And the USB port is a slave type one, not a host, so you can't connect a device (printer) to NXT.